# Как расположить блоки с помощью flexbox?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка

у меня есть макет (Фото предоставляю ниже), шапку сверстал самостоятельно, осталось сделать вторую часть макета (главную часть), подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно расположить блоки с помощью `flex-box`? Блоки на скриншоте обвел в красную рамку.

[image: ht]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

flex-direction: column; + flex-wrap:wrap; + max-height такой вот  хак

```css
.items {
  display: flex;
  width: 880px;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-height: 400px;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.item:nth-of-type(1) {
  height: 400px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.item:nth-of-type(2),
.item:nth-of-type(3),
.item:nth-of-type(4),
.item:nth-of-type(5),
.item:nth-of-type(6),
.item:nth-of-type(7) {
  height: 180px;
  background: #ccc
}
```

```html
<div class="items">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: разумеется смотреть на полный экран

Comment: Спасибо большое, сам бы даже и не додумался до такого решения!((